# Cannot run android application because non exit value 1

Tags: android, excel

Before I put fillo.jar (http://codoid.com/fillo/), I could run its programm to my phone, but after I add fillo.jar as dependency library, I couldnt run its programm. Beside that I make simple java programm, and include its jar, it can work normally. Here my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cashier.apps.cashiersoft"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/btsdk.jar')
    compile 'com.codoid.products:fillo:1.14'
}
```

I got this error after build.gradle process :

```
    13:18:20.231 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    13:18:20.232 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13:19:00.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:19:00.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:19:00.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:19:00.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
13:19:00.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
13:19:00.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
13:19:00.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:19:00.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
13:19:00.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.


13:18:20.232 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
13:18:59.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$SchemaTypeLoaderCache$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$SchemaTypeLoaderCache$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$ThreadedReader$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$ThreadedReader$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCodeGenerator$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCodeGenerator$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaResourceManager$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaResourceManager$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XsbDumper$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XsbDumper$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.JamUtils$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.JamUtils$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem ? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have the .JAR supplied, you don't have to add another Gradle dependency for the same component:

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile files('libs/btsdk.jar')
        compile 'com.codoid.products:fillo:1.14' // <– Erase this line (or remove the .JAR from your project)
    }
```

Comment: already tried with external library like you mentioned in this comment, but I got same error, then I make dependency, but still get same error when run gradle process

Comment: i added external library for java testing programm, different with this one(android). So I used two ways : with external library and non external.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change buildToolVersion from 22.0.1 to 23.0.2.

If it is not working, clean and build the project; otherwise, restart your Android Studio from file -> Invalid cache and restart.

Comment: same result brother.

Comment: defaultConfig {

multiDexEnabled true
}

Comment: Try the above statment in default Config block.